# Android stream off YouTube returns null?

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming

I recently learned of the YouTube API that was made available by google. I’m creating an Android application that would allow its users to watch a video (or videos) off you YouTube through the app.

So far, with the help of [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTO5a1IeBl8) online tutorial; I’ve integrated web services into the app through which I’m trying to acquire a list of video uploads from a particular YouTube account/channel. It works fine so far, but whenever I launch the app and click on the button to get the data from YouTube, it returns an empty list.

Below is the class that interacts with the YouTube public API. I’ve got other classes included to help achieve the goal, but seeing that am having a an empty list returned, i’m guessing I might have missed/gone wrong somewhere here…or maybe not.

```
private static final String YouTubeVideoUrl = 
        "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Patrick%20Tolani/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc";
private static final String logTag = "OpenHeavenReflection";
private static byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
private static final int http_is_ok = 200;

public static class ApiException extends Exception{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ApiException(String msg){
        super (msg);
    }

    public ApiException(String msg, Throwable thr){
        super(msg, thr);
    }
}

/*
 * Download most recent uploads from a particular YouTube account user
 * @params
 * @return An array of json strings returned by the YouTube API
 * @throws ApiException
 */
protected static synchronized String getVideosFromServer(String... params) throws ApiException{

    String url = YouTubeVideoUrl;
    String returnVal = null;

    Log.d(logTag,"Fetching " + url);

    //Here I'll now create a HTTP client and a request object.
    HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

    try {
        //Here I'll execute the request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
        if(status.getStatusCode() != http_is_ok){
            throw new ApiException("Invalid response from YouTube" + 
                    status.toString());
        }

        //Here I'll process the content.
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int countRead = 0;
        while((countRead = is.read(buff)) != -1){
            content.write(buff, 0, countRead);
        }
        /*this returns a string of the recent uploads 
         * by the specified YouTube account.
         */
        returnVal = new String(content.toByteArray());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new ApiException("Problem connecting to Server" + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

Can you help me understand why am getting an empty list?

Comment: Give this syntax a try first: Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenHeaves.class); Your IDE should ask you to import the class. It's possible there's a typo somewhere in that string.

Comment: @IkaiLan I made changes to the previous solution, thanks to the tutorial provided above. But will definitely try your suggestion, as I still have the old solution.